# Multi Tenant in Codeiginiter

Tags: database, codeigniter, multi-tenant

I want to develop multi tenant codeigniter application. One thing we're considering is building it to be a multi-tenant application because the core features are reusable for a number of businesses we work with. However, I have very little experience with multi-tenant apps.

My question is - does anyone in this community know of any good resources (tutorials, documentation, etc) or personal experience they can share about building multi-tenant applications with CodeIgniter.

Single database, single code-base Option

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50601259/multitenant-codeigniter/50618037#50618037 looks like the same

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.